# コメント文字のみを含む行は「段落の区切り」扱いしたい

Tags: vim

段落オブジェクト (ap/ip) を使うと「空行」で区切られた「段落」を対象に各種の操作を行うことができますが，ここでの「空行」の定義を拡張したいです．すなわち，コメント文字1文字のみを含む行は「空行」扱いをして，ここで段落オブジェクトが区切られるような設定を行うことは可能でしょうか？

例えば，以下のような LaTeX ソースを編集している場面で，`|` のカーソル位置で `gqap` による段落の整形をしようとすると，下記ソース全体が整形されてしまい不便です．ここでは4行目を段落の区切りとしての「空行」扱いにして，上3行だけが整形の対象となるようにしたいのですが，どのようにしたらよいでしょうか？

```latex
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.|
%
\begin{equation}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}
%
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
fugiatnulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

私の知る限り、標準機能でこれを行う方法はないと思います。

標準機能以外で段落の拡張を行うには、そのような新しい text-object を作成して、それを ap/ip に割り当てることで実現可能です。

具体的な作成方法まで触れると長くなるため、今回の回答はここまでとしておこうと思います。必要でしたら別途お答えします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます．ちょうどそんな気がしていたので，kana/vim-textobj-user を使用して求める text-object の作成を試みていたのですが，`'pattern': ['\n\n', '\n\n']` でデフォルトの「段落オブジェクト」の挙動を再現できなかったところで詰まっています（ここでの正規表現は行指向なのではないかと疑っていますが）．もしよろしければ，「kana/vim-textobj-user の関数による text-object 定義を使うとできる」など，方針のところまで教えていただけると幸いに思います．（具体的な関数定義までは自分で考えてみるので，そこまで時間を割いていただかなくても大丈夫です）

Comment: 調べたところ、textobj-user でのパターンを2つ指定する方法は `searchpairpos()` 関数を使用しており、これはネストしたパターンを検出する機構が入っているため、start と end に同じパターンを指定してしまうとうまく動かないようです。関数による定義であれば独自の処理で textobj の範囲を決定できるため、定義可能だと思います。

Comment: 思ったよりコードが長くなって驚きなのですが，確かに kana/vim-textobj-user で自作関数を用いて textobj を定義する方法で実装できました．
https://github.com/wtsnjp/dotfiles/commit/13f6d179cfd22b8de62a43c6b2ed000266883720